# Create a listbox background using XML Drawable

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, drawable, android-xml

I'm trying to create a complex xml drawable to represent a listbox, setting it as a background of a TextView.

Following there is there a screenshot of what I want to obtain and what I get instead.

[image: listbox screenshot]

As you can see I want to put my arrow in a gradient gray box on the right.

Looking at android documentation, it seems that xml shapes supports the size tag, as reported here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape , but i can't get it working!

Here there is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#999999" />
      <corners android:radius="5dp" />
      <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    </shape>
  </item>

  <item>
      <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#999999" />
        <corners android:topRightRadius="5dp" android:bottomRightRadius="5dp" />
        <gradient android:startColor="#606060" android:endColor="#303030" android:angle="270" />
        <padding android:top="7dp" android:bottom="7dp" android:right="7dp" />
      </shape>
  </item>

  <item>
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/listbox_arrow_icon" android:gravity="right|fill_vertical" android:tileMode="disabled" />
  </item>

</layer-list>
```

I tried specifying android:width in shape tag, as specified here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable.html#attr_android:width, but it doesn't work too.

I don't want to do it using code, but if it's unavoidable, in the end, I think i'll build a component to use in the place of TextView for this stuff.

Thanks for your help!

@EDIT
Sorry, during copy&paste I dropped the solid tag of the first shape! Fixed!

Comment: try with `android:color="#FFFFFF"` instead of #999999

Comment: I forgot to paste the solid xml tag in the first shape, however the problem isn't about the bg color but about the width of the box!
Specifying the width of the second shape, the one that draw the arrow background, doesn't work, and, as I wrote, I tried with <shape android:shape="rectangle" android:width="30dp"> for the second shape but it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  <item><shape>
        <solid android:color="#fff" />

        <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#10000000" />

        <corners android:radius="6dp" />

        <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#10000000" android:startColor="#10FFFFFF" />
    </shape></item>
```